# Как определять переключение месяцев в календаре react-dates?

Tags: reactjs

Я использую react-dates для календаря в своём веб-приложении. И у меня возникла необходимость отслеживать переключение между месяцами. Т.е. мне надо знать, когда пользователь переключил календарь на определённый месяц.

Вот мой календарь.

```js
<DayPickerSingleDateController
   numberOfMonths={1}
   date={this.state.dateForCalendar}
   isDayHighlighted={this.highlited}
   renderCalendarDay={this.renderDay}
   onDateChange={this.daySelected}
   firstDayOfWeek={0}
/>
```

Я нашёл в документации свойства onPrevMonthClick и onNextMonthClick, которые принимают на вход функцию. Я думал это как раз то что мне нужно, но при вставке этих свойств компилятор выдаёт ошибку

```js
./src/features/schedule/index.js
  Line 178:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  176 |                         {this.state.calendar_on &&
  177 |                         <DayPickerSingleDateController
> 178 |                             onPrevMonthClick: {text => {console.log(text)}}
      |                                               ^
  179 |                             numberOfMonths={1}
  180 |                             date={this.state.dateForCalendar}
  181 |                             isDayHighlighted={this.highlited}
```

Что я не так делаю? (даже если я передаю функцию, которая не принимает аргументов или возвращает булево значение)

Comment: onPrevMonthClick={text => {console.log(text)}}

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для передачи данных от родителя к ребенку, через `props` необходимо указывать передаваемые данные через знак равенства `=`, а не через двоеточие `:`. Собственно, `props` - это неизменяемый объект, предназначенный только для чтения, `props` - это просто аргумент функции, с которым мы можем работать внутри, но не изменять (его изменение может повлечь за собой проблемы). В Вашем случае достаточно внести мелкую правку в код (заменить двоеточие `:` на знак равенства `=`):

```
<DayPickerSingleDateController
   onPrevMonthClick={text=>{console.log(text)}}
   onNextMonthClick={text=>{console.log(text)}}
   numberOfMonths={1}
   date={this.state.dateForCalendar}
   isDayHighlighted={this.highlited}
   renderCalendarDay={this.renderDay}
   onDateChange={this.daySelected}
   firstDayOfWeek={0}
/>
```

Однако использование стрелочной функции в рендеринге не рекомендуюется. Потому что при использовании стрелочной функции в рендере, каждый раз при рендеринге компонента создается новая функция, которая может нарушить оптимизацию и добавить тормоза. Про это пишут в документации по React: [Arrow Function in Render](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render)

Comment: Да ну я уже понял как сильно затупил)) Копировал из примера и забыл поменять двоеточие на равно. Теперь стыдно за вопрос)

Comment: @cheerful_weasel зато вопрос правильно оформлен и сразу ясно в чем у Вас дело )

Comment: А насчёт стрелочной функции я в курсе с недавних пор. Использую её внутри рендера только для отладки.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel да, хорошо знать про стрелочные функции некоторые детали.